# How can I control CSS with a button in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I Can not find the right code for the JS to control CSS. Upon opening link I need the "transform" to be off , and then turn on and toggle back and forth "transform" with the button. It started as an on/off mute button needing no css , so my paths ?

The buttons ( play/pause/etc)are in a div . Their function are in JS and all work, except, I need this one to reach into CSS but can't find my brain. A delete of the CSS and it opens and runs everything else and runs the way I would like.  Thanks.

```
    <button onclick="transform()">mirror</button> 

    #myplayer {
  
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
  
 var player = document.getElementById("myplayer");

    function transform() { 
        if (player.transform)
            player.transform = false
        else
            player.transform = true
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

```
function transform() { 
            if (player.transform)
                player.transform = false
            else
                player.transform = true
        }
```

To this

```
function transform() { 
        if (player.style.transform){
            player.style.transform = "";
        }
        else{
            player.style.transform="rotate(180deg)";
        }
    }
```

Comment: this worked only after I deleted the CSS #transform   rotateY(180deg)..                     function transform() { 
        if (player.style.transform){
            player.style.transform = "";
        }
        else{
            player.style.transform="rotate(180deg)";
        }
    }

Answer (score 2):

Get the button element, add a click event handler to it, within the handler once the button is clicked, grab the video element then use [.classList.toggle('class-name')](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to toggle a class.

```js
document.getElementById("transformPlayer").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("player").classList.toggle('transform180')
});
```

```css
.transform180 {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<button id="transformPlayer">mirror</button>


<video id="player" controls width="250">
    <source src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.webm"
            type="video/webm">
    <source src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.mp4"
            type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a class

```js
const player = document.querySelector('#myplayer')
const button = document.querySelector('button')

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  player.classList.toggle('rotate')
})
```

```css
#myplayer {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  color: white;
}

#myplayer.rotate {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<button>mirror</button>
<div id="myplayer">:)</div>
```